# Capturing and displaying output from within Julia

Tags: julia, stdio

I looked everywhere for this so I am putting it here for the weary traveler;

Question: How do I capture the full output of a variable to a file from within a julia script?

i.e. :

```
#script.jl
y = f(x)
y > out.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is here:

https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/issues/455
If you want to display the output then:

```
show(STDOUT, "text/plain", x)
```

If you want to pipe the output to a file then:

```
x=rand(Float32, 32,32)
f = open("log.txt", "w")
    write(f, string(x))
close(f)
```

And for larger x or prettier output

```
x = rand(Float32, 1028,1028);
f = open("log.txt", "w");
writedlm(f, x);
close(f);
```